# How do I assign existing array values into an array pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a program that needs to use a large array (700,000 elements). I tried to assign it as per a normal array:

```
byte array1[700000] = {0xE8, 0x39, 0xF4, 0xB7, 0x69, ~~699995 other values~~ };
```

But then, I was met with a segmentation fault. After a bit of research, it was suggested that I put it on the heap. So, I did:

```
byte* array1 = (byte*) malloc(700000 * sizeof(byte) /* Just to be safe */);
```

I've used pointers before, and normally I would use a loop to mess around with it. But, in this case, all of the values already exist. How do I put all of those in the new `array1`? **I cannot use external files (i.e. I cannot read from a .txt file).**

---

This does not work (Too many initializer values according to Visual Studio):

```
byte* array1 = (byte*) malloc(700000 * sizeof(byte));
array1 = { ~~ 700k comma-separated values ~~ };
```

---

Sample on how I plan to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    byte big_array[700000] = {0xE8, 0x39, 0xF4, ~~699995 other values~~ };
    some_function(big_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not trying to keep your first code `byte array1[10000]=...` but adding `static` to not store your array on the stack ?

Comment: Providing us with the complete context of the program this is a part of would help us help you. Also, `malloc` is used in C; always use `new[]` in C++.

Comment: @qxz working on it.

Comment: @J.Piquard Making it static solved the problem. I would be glad to accept it as an answer if you post it as one.

Comment: Do you need to modify the values? or they are read only?

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you should use a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<byte> array1 = {0xE8, 0x39, 0xF4, 0xB7, 0x69, ~~9995 other values~~ };
```